# Workaround for X-Frame-Options:deny or sameorgin?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-headers

I'm displaying web pages (from other domains) in an IFrame to have navigation at the side. However, some websites have the header `X-Frame-Options:deny` or `X-Frame-Options:sameorigin`, which prevents the pages from loading in my iframe. Is there a workaround to this? How would I display the web page?

I noticed that StumbleUpon has the same issue. Here's an example with the `X-Frame-Options` issue: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/53D0nJ/news.yahoo.com/worlds-dumbest-idea-taxing-solar-energy-111300623.html/

Answer (score 1):

No.

It would be entirely pointless for browser vendors to provide a way for websites to say *Don't let third parties put my content in a frame* if they also provided a way for third parties to tell browsers to ignore that instruction.

The closest you could come would be to copy their content so it is accessible via a URL on your own server. That approach would probably cause you to run afoul of international copyright law.